# HTML Table with spaces

Tags: html, css

This is an easy question, but it's super frustrating for someone who is not using html for ages. My html table can be seen at the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/mr_muscle/Lw5o7ary/

with below html:

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Account status:</th>
        <th>Portfolios invested:</th>
        <th>Date joined:</th>
        <th>MangoPay status:</th>
        <th>NorthRow status:</th>
        <th>Investor type:</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>status</td>
        <td>Number of portfolios</td>
        <td>17 Feb, 2019</td>
        <td>Approved</td>
        <td>Approved</td>
        <td>Inexperienced</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>Suspend user</td>
        <td colspan='2'>Member for 1 y, 10m</td>
        <td>Change</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Which will give me tables without spaces. How to achieved something similar to this:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Take a look on [`border-spacing` at MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing).

Answer (score 2):

Change Style accordingly

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 15px;
}

th {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 25px;
}

td {
  margin: 51px;
  padding: 29px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account status:</th>
      <th>Portfolios invested:</th>
      <th>Date joined:</th>
      <th>MangoPay status:</th>
      <th>NorthRow status:</th>
      <th>Investor type:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>status</td>
      <td>Number of portfolios</td>
      <td>17 Feb, 2019</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>Inexperienced</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>Suspend user</td>
      <td colspan='2'>Member for 1 y, 10m</td>
      <td>Change</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a padding to your table cells:

```css
td {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account status:</th>
      <th>Portfolios invested:</th>
      <th>Date joined:</th>
      <th>MangoPay status:</th>
      <th>NorthRow status:</th>
      <th>Investor type:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>status</td>
      <td>Number of portfolios</td>
      <td>17 Feb, 2019</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>Inexperienced</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>Suspend user</td>
      <td colspan='2'>Member for 1 y, 10m</td>
      <td>Change</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```